# HttpClient C#. Можно ли узнать размер тела запроса раньше его загрузки

Tags: c#, http

Метод GetAsync(uri) является асинхронным. Результатом его выполнения является объект HttpResponseMessage, который имеет свойство Content. Content включает в себя метод асинхронный метод ReadAsStringAsync.

Это наводит на мысль, что мы получаем HttpResponseMessage, в котором тело еще не загружено, а заголовки уже загружены. Т.е мы может проверить размер тела и если это не нужно, то не грузить. Но я вижу другую картину: получение HttpResponseMessage приводит к полной загрузке тела.  Так ли это или я ошибаюсь? Как же все таки предотвратить лишний расход трафика?

Пример:

```
public static void Test()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            //Ссылка на тяжелый  файл
            var uri = new Uri("http://video.seclub.org/dl2.php?f=18848");

            client.GetAsync(uri).ContinueWith((responce) =>
            {
                //Вопреки ожиданиям сюда не попадаем до тех пор, пока полностью не будет загружно тело ответа

                Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
                watch.Start();

                var bodyDownloading = responce.Result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                byte[] body = bodyDownloading.Result;

                watch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine($"Загрузили {body.Length / 1024 / 1024} mb за {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000} секунд? Не думаю!");

            }).Wait();


        }
```

Comment: не приводит к полной загрузке конечно. иначе ReadAs...Async не был бы асинхронным

Comment: А вот и приводит. Посмотрите мою правку - я добавил пример.

Comment: Как вы определяете в какой момент тело ответа было полностью загружено?

Comment: дык второй параметр GetAsync нужно поставить в HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead

Comment: Очень-очень дельное замечание. Спасибо )

Comment: Не вижу, как тут отменить вопрос решенным и отметить ответ лучшим